# How do I include a keystore in my android APK's classpath?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, classpath

What I need to do is place a generated keystore (.jks file, it contains an SSL certificate) into the classpath directory of the APK, but I have no idea how to do this.  I need to do this so that a library can access the SSL certificate (NanoHttpd).

I'm using Android Studio and gradle, and I assume it is something like this:

```
android {
    from('src/main/certs') {
        include 'ssl_keystore.jks'
        into('classes')
    }
}
```

Or maybe something like:

```
android {
    classpath += files('src/main/certs')
}
```

But these do not seem to work.  Gradle complains either about 'from' not being found in the gradle build language or:

```
Could not find property 'classpath' on
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@6dabfbd1.
```

I've tried a ton of different things here, and I've lost track.  I have absolutely no idea what the correct way to do this is, and I cannot find any information on it at all.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you try to sign the `.apk` Android Studio will prompt a dialog allowing you to select the location of the keys. Go to `Build->Generate Signed apk`

Comment: I use a separate keystore for signing my application, is there any other option?  And does that actually include the keystore in the classpath?  I thought it just used it to sign the APK, seems a bit weird if it did.

Comment: Um, putting arbitrary files on the classpath is not something that you normally do in Android. You may wish to consider using a better Web server, one that was written with Android in mind (and, on the whole, less than 20 years ago). Ion, for example, has a Web server component that IIRC supports SSL.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that my app is not a normal app - it runs only in fairly specific environments and would never be distributed via the playstore or the like (we control the hardware in 99%, maybe 100% of cases.)  If it is possible to add a file to the classpath I'd like to do it and make this approach work so I do not need to rewrite the server, but if it isn't possible then I guess I am left without a choice.  Having said that, NanoHttpd is in active development and they claim somewhat common usage on android.

Comment: @CommonsWare After reflecting on your comment, I looked through NanoHttpd and found a way to simply pass in a loaded keystore.  I am now loading the keystore via the assets folder, thanks for heads up.

Comment: @jconder, can you share the code that resolved your issue? I am facing a similar issue.